# How to force/reproduce FullGC in JVM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, apache-zookeeper, heartbeat

Is there a way to force/reproduce FullGC in JVM  for x seconds ? Basically I needed this to verify root cause of an issue in certain heart beat based app ( a client of zookeeper)

**EDIT**: Does unix command `kill -STOP <pid>` and `kill -CONT <pid>` simulate FullGC ( stop the world behaviour) ?

Comment: regarding edit part, I found following but it wont answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221158/do-gc-pauses-and-kill-stop-produce-the-same-behavior

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate a very long stop-the-world event on HotSpot JVMs which is similar to FullGC from user's point of view.

HotSpot doesn't put [safepoints](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html) into counted int loops, because it assumes that they will terminate just "fast enough"(In this case server compiler will generate more optimal loop code). Even a stop-the-world will have to wait until this loop will finish. In the following example we have very tight loop which do small but expensive computations without safepoint polling:

```
public static double slowpoke(int iterations) {
    double d = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < iterations; j++) {
        d += Math.log(Math.E * j);
    }
    return d;
}
```

In order to reproduce FullGC like pause you can use something like this:

```
public class SafepointTest {

    public static double slowpoke(int iterations) {
        double d = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < iterations; j++) {
            d += Math.log(Math.E * j);
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double sideEffect = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    sideEffect = slowpoke(999999999);
                }
                System.out.println("result = " + sideEffect);
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while (true){
                    System.out.println("Delay " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp));
                    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //trigger stop-the-world 
                    System.gc();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

As a result:

```
Delay 5
Delay 4
Delay 30782
Delay 21819
Delay 21966
Delay 22812
Delay 22264
Delay 21988
```

In order to increase delay just change argument value for `slowpoke(int iterations)` function.

Here is useful diagnostic commands:

- `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` this will actually report pause time for all safepoints into GC log. Unfortunately output from this option lacks timestamps.
- `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` this two options will force JVM to report reason and timings after each safepoint.

### EDIT

Regarding to Edit: from user's point of view `kill -STOP` and `kill -CONT` have the same semantics as STW i.e. application doesn't respond on any request. However, this requires access to command line and doesn't consume resources(CPU, memory).

Comment: Thanks !! Can you check updated question description