# Java process hangs, no thread dump could be taken

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, dump, freeze

I am facing with a strange case. I'd be glad if you could share your comments.

We have solution running on Java 1.6.085 and sometimes Java process is getting hang in production. The solution is running on Linux server.
I investigated GC logs, there is no Full GC. Pause times also look reasonable.
Then we tried to take a thread dump when case happens however kill -3, ./jstack or ./jstack -F do not work. No thread dump could be taken. What could be the reason for that ? Any ideas on investigating the issue ?

BR
-emre

Comment: jstack/kill requires stop-the-world pause. In some cases it is impossible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917951/how-to-force-reproduce-fullgc-in-jvm  Could you please provide system output with following settings -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 ?

Comment: @Ivan, I think -F does not require a STW pause, it captures stacks of running threads.

Comment: 1.6 is ancient, why don't you update first to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: You should find that Java 8 does a better job of tracing under these sort of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

After a while it is understood that the issue occured due to  pstack and qdb commands which are executed on java process for operational purposes. Somehow pstack and qdb suspends the java process. Therefore we couldnt be able to take thread or heap dump

Answer (score 0):

We're using jConsole with the [topthreads plugin](https://arnhem.luminis.eu/new_version_topthreads_jconsole_plugin/) to analyze such cases. The plugin uses JMX to check the thread runtimes and displays their CPU usage since start of the tracking procedure as well as the current stack trace for each thread.

To connect our servers from a local machine we use tunnels in putty, i.e. we first connect to the server via putty and then connect jConsole to a local port which is tunneled to the server.

Comment: Thx for the repIy, I downloaded the new version and  tried to use it however new tab was not seen. Do you have any idea ? ./jconsole -pluginpath /home/mmsuper/topthreads.jar

Comment: @emrenak hmm, were using jconsole on Windows clients and our jconsole.bat (which adds some JBoss-specific libs to the classpath) contains this line: `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jconsole.exe" -J"-Djava.class.path=%CLASSPATH%" -pluginpath C:\whatever\topthreads-1.1.jar` - so unless the path is wrong it should work. Did you check permissions, name etc.?